# Which site to use for managing and finding out about wikis?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to find out more about wikis, how to manage one, and what makes a good wiki. Which of the stackexchange sites should I use for this? Is it StackOverflow? I note these similar topics have been closed on StackOverflow:

[Maintaining a Programmer Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247967/maintaining-a-programmer-wiki)

[Good wiki software for internal company use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647274/good-wiki-software-for-internal-company-use)

Comment: This is a comment and _not_ an answer... the immediate temptation is to say webapps.se, but their [help pages](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) suggest this is right on the boundary and may not be on-topic. Though they do have a few wiki questions it's hardly any. Your potential questions also sound very broad - which mean they could be closed wherever you post  them. Do you have an example question that you intend to ask?

Comment: You can possible look at [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) this is pretty good for internal use. This also integrates with [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) which is a pretty nice issue tracker / project management type application. **DISCLAIMER:** I have no association with atlassian, I just so happened to work with Confluence and JIRA at my previous company.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, point noted about question being broad; some broad wiki questions have been answered on stackoverflow, but others I posted have been closed. The wiki in question will be for my company, and I want to know what gives good user experience and encourages people to participate in the wiki. A walkthrough on how to use the wiki? Having a good administrator doing edits and reclassifying pages?

Comment: @jacqijvv, confluence is an option, in that regard we would like to be able to compare confluence to say tikiwiki by asking people about the usage experiences of linking jira task management to relevant wiki subjects on say tiki.